# How can I stop Outlook from screwing up images inserted into an HTML email?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, save, dpi

(using: Windows 8.1 [running at 125% DPI], Outlook 2013, Exchange 2007 )

Hi

I have a problem getting my graphic designs which I am creating on Outlook emails to come out correctly if I have changed the Window DPI setting to 125% (i.e. 120 DPI).

What happens is the moment that I insert an image into the body of an email in Outlook the image is resized (physically made larger by 25%, by blurring in my case). In some instances this resizing only happens the moment you press Send.

Either way what the recipient sees is an enlarged, blurred image. Nightmare.

At present the ONLY answer seems to be to change the Windows DPI to 96DPI. However one is forced to log out of Windows for this to take effect. However the Windows text on any moderately high res screen is painfully small and I am then soon forced by hurting eyes to change it back again which involves logging out and in again.

I have tried creating images of 120 DPI (difficult but possible) however this does not seem to work.

Gmail is out of the question for several reasons.

I have tried Thunderbird but it too enlarger images when displayed and also the only way to get it to work with Exchange is to install a plugin. I have use ExQillia but that will blow up in 60 days and thereafter it costs $10 which is not acceptable.

If any one knows a way to stop Outlook 2013 from re-sizing please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You can't change the Save For Web PPI setting. -- You also can't control what other people in Outlook may see. Inserting an image at a higher PPI could easily mean everyone else viewing in Outlook sees an image which is too large.

Comment: Don't use 'save for web'? Not sure if this is a graphic design question, though. This seems more like an issue with Outlook more than anything.

Comment: I am bemused by this being put on hold. To get clear I am trying to do "Graphic Design" on my outbound emails. i.e. I am trying to send emails whose images have not been physically blurred by Outlook at the time of sending.  WTF?
No, it is not an Outlook issue. I understand precisely how Outlook works. It has worked exactly like this for the last decade. This is an issue with how to created graphic files that have the DPI setting that Outlook needs.
P.S. If you claim this to be "off" the topic of Graphic Design tell me, pray, exactly where else do you propose my issue be put?  - OP

Comment: This seems to be more an Outlook configuration problem than Photoshop. I don't use Outlook, but I would be very surprised if they have not incorporated an option that prevents scaling of images. If you are inserting images for sending to other people, you may consider using an alternate method of transmission like via Dropbox, Copy, and send a link to the image(s) in the e-mail.

Comment: I have searched widely & asked around. The answer (jaw-droppingly) is that no, there is no option to stop Outlook from physically resizing images. 
Alternative methods of sending an image are completely missing the point. I need the images (e.g. annotated screen grabs) to be in the correct context within an email - i.e. I regularly need to insert images to explain a particular point part way through an email. Setting up with Dropbox or Copy would require a link within the email. More often than not the users will fail to click on any links. I don't want the users to have to click on anything!

Comment: Proper configuration would be to use HTML img src links to link to image on servers rather than trying to include the images inline.

Comment: Another, and perhaps far more controllable approach may be to create the document in Word with the images embedded in places you like and then converting it to PDF to attach to the e-mail. Yet another option is to use a different e-mail software, perhaps Thunderbird.

Comment: Voting to leave closed as this question question is still tech support. However it really might be a good fit for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) now.

Comment: OK I have re-framed the question.  Converting HTML emails into PDF is inconvenient for the recipient. i.e. forces users to make another click and wait for a PDF browser to open.
I have no tried installing Thunderbird (see re-framed question), however feels like a hammer to crack a nut - it is also not free if using ExQuillia - in effect it is $10/year just to get Outlook to send emails without trashing images.  
The online images suggestion is a good one. Or it would be if I could get a work flow together.  You cant paste a URL in directly and I cant get OneDrive to work. More later on that.